# Proof: A graph that does not contain any closed walks with odd length is bipartite.

Tags: proof-verification, graph-theory, alternative-proof, bipartite-graphs

I came across this proof in the book Mathematics for CSE by E.Lehman and F.T. Leighton(2010 version). They prove that a graph with no walks of odd length is bipartite. Here is the proof:
[image: The proof]

4 IMPLIES 1 means that the property 4 implies property 1. Here is a photo for reference: [image: The description of the properties of Graph G]

So, basically in the proof they use contradiction and go onto say that G' is not bipartite there must be a pair of nodes u1 and u2 whose length of the shortest path to an arbitrary node v in G' is either odd or even. Does this statement not hold true for a bipartite graph? If not how?

And can anyone please simplify the proof for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the contradiction is that the shortest path is both odd and even, not (as you write) odd or even.

Comment: I don't think so. The contradiction is that the union of the path from u1 to v, u2 to v and e(the edge between u1 and u2) is odd. It states that u1 and u2 are both in L or both in R.

Comment: You’ve misunderstood what is shown. On the assumption that $G'$ is not bipartite, the authors show that there are adjacent nodes $u_1$ and $u_2$ in $V'$ such that $\operatorname{dist}(u_1)$ and $\operatorname{dist}(u_2)$ have the same parity, i.e., **both** are odd or **both** are even. This is **not** true for a bipartite graph, because it immediately implies that $\operatorname{dist}(u_1)+\operatorname{dist}(u_1)$ is even and hence that $\operatorname{dist}(u_1)+1+\operatorname{dist}(u_1)$, the length of the closed walk $P_1\cup\{e\}\cup P_2$, is odd, an impossibility in a bipartite graph.